# dynamically adjust class to make text fit in small box

Tags: jquery, html, css

Okay, I have a number inside a tiny box, although the output is dynamic it is predictable enough to know that there will more than likely be no more than 5 characters in this box. What I want to do is, have a jQuery script that counts the number of characters in the box and adds the number as a class to the box. Like This:

```
<div class="num">2443</div>

$('.num').addClass(numOfChars); 
// numOfChars will be different for each, but will be detected
```

When the script is finished, the box will look like this:

```
<div class="num 4">2443</div>
```

If the box had 5 characters in it it would look like this:

```
<div class="num 5">12556</div>
```

There will be multiple boxes present on a page so it needs to be able to run for all of them. Is there any method of doing such a thing?

Please ask questions. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.num').each(function() {
    var l = $(this).html().length;
    $(this).addClass('size' + l);
  });
});

</script>
<style type="text/css">
  .num { border: solid 1px red; }
  .size4 { width: 100px; }
  .size5 { width: 200px; }
</style>

<div class="num">2443</div>
<div class="num">12556</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add a class equals to it's text length to any element with `num` class you can do this:

```
   $('.num').each(function(){
                    $(this).addClass(
                             'n'+
                             $(this).text().length.toString()
                     )
   });
```

I added the `n` string before the adding class name because class name shouldn't start with numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can get `innerHTML` of the div as a string, calculate its length and add that as a class.  You'll need to do something like `"" + len` to convert that number to a string.

Comment: how do you get the length of `innerHTML`?

Comment: On a particular div, you can have `document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML.length`